# Downgrade Parse Server

Tags: parse-server, downgrade

I've been trying for 2 hours straight now, to downgrade Parse Server from `3.0.0` to `2.8.4` and I fail every time!

I changed it from `package.json`, `npm install`, go to dashboard, still: `server version 3.0.0`!

Here are the logs of the installation:

```
npm install
npm WARN deprecated uws@10.148.1: stop using this version
parse-server-example@1.4.0 /root/parse-server-example
├─┬ parse-dashboard@1.2.0
│ └─┬ express@4.16.3
│   ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
│   ├── encodeurl@1.0.2 
│   ├─┬ finalhandler@1.1.1
│   │ └── encodeurl@1.0.2 
│   ├─┬ send@0.16.2
│   │ └── encodeurl@1.0.2 
│   └─┬ serve-static@1.13.2
│     └── encodeurl@1.0.2 
└─┬ parse-server@2.8.4 
  ├─┬ @parse/push-adapter@3.0.0-alpha2
  │ └─┬ parse@1.11.1 
  │   └─┬ ws@3.3.3 
  │     └── ultron@1.1.1 
  ├── @parse/simple-mailgun-adapter@1.0.2 
  ├── commander@2.16.0 
  ├─┬ express@4.16.2
  │ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
  │ └── encodeurl@1.0.2 
  ├── lru-cache@4.1.2 
  ├─┬ mongodb@3.1.1 
  │ └─┬ mongodb-core@3.1.0 
  │   └── bson@1.0.9 
  ├─┬ parse@1.11.1 
  │ └─┬ ws@3.3.3 
  │   └── ultron@1.1.1 
  └── request@2.85.0 

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /root/parse-server-example/node_modules/.staging/node-pre-gyp-49f396d5
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/root/parse-server-example/node_modules/.staging/node-pre-gyp-49f396d5' -> '/root/parse-server-example/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/root/parse-server-example/node_modules/.staging/node-pre-gyp-49f396d5' -> '/root/parse-server-example/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/parse-server-example/npm-debug.log
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely never run this command without looking at what's going to be deleting and understanding whether or not it's OK, but try doing `rm -rf <path>/node_modules/*`. Maybe wait for a comment or two confirming. Seriously don't just randomly do an `rm -rf` command because someone on the internet told you to.

But in this case, you should be fine deleting node_modules, and a package-lock.json if it exists, and running `npm install` to do a bit of a fresh install of what's in your package.json.

Seriously, absolutely don't do this until you look up what it is you're doing and verify it'd be OK.

package-lock.json tracks the changes in the versions of modules you use. node_modules is where `npm install` installs all the modules to. When you run the command, it checks your node_modules vs your package.json to see if there are any more recent versions that match your criteria. Idk why it's not downgrading, but if your package.json is set up right, this should give it a fresh install and *should* work.

Do at your own risk, though.